# Are the or pipes not working?

Tags: java, or-operator

For my very first Java project I'm trying to make a simple text-based game. It seems like the or pipes do not work and when I try to enter something in after it doesn't work; I have to restart it.

```
    public void GameStart() {
    String playerName = "Player";
    String Command = "Choice";
        System.out.println("Type Start to start game!");
    if(in.nextLine().equals("Start") || in.nextLine().equals("start")) {
        Help();
        print("Type Begin to start game :D");
        if(in.nextLine().equals("Begin") || in.nextLine().equals("begin")) {
            System.out.println("Who are you?");
```

Start and Begin works, but having the first letter lowercase like I used || for doesn't. When I use those I have to restart it because I can't type anything, but I clearly have or pipes that says to use either one. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: what do you think happens when you call `in.nextLine()`?

Comment: `in.nextLine()` is probably waiting for more input. Trying saving the input in a variable and checking the value of that.

Comment: As a general rule, I've found it useful to *never* make state changes "inline" with other computations/evaluations. (In your case, the state changes are when you read input, which you do "inline" with a Boolean condition. Another example in incrementing, e.g, `i++`.) I have always found it clearer and easier to get right when you keep them separate. Put the state changes before or after other operations, in a separate statement. Had you done so here, your problem would have never occurred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String str = in.nextLine();
str.equalsIgnoreCase("Start");
```

It will check both the lower and upper cases. You don't need to call equals() method twice, so it will optimize your code and readability.

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks this worked! Although, for me it's equalsIgnoreCase instead of equal :P

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Yes it's equalsIgnoreCase !! Syntex Error :P

Comment: @AnkurMahajan It's not syntax error, it will be "cannot find symbol" error :p

Answer (score 16):

```
in.nextLine().equals("Start") || in.nextLine().equals("start")
```

This will be executed from left to right, so first `in.nextLine().equals("Start")` is executed.

Let's say you input `"start"`. Left side returns `false`.  Evaluation of the whole expression continues. The right side is executed, `in.nextLine().equals("start")`. So, it reads *another* line, waits for your *another* input. This is not what you want.

To fix this (this is also a general rule): *do not change the state in the `if` condition*. In other words: *expression in the condition should have no [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science))*.

You can assign the result of the method which is changing the state, `in.nextLine()`, to a reference:

```
String line = in.nextLine();
if (line.equals("Start") || line.equals("start"))
```

You can also write the condition like:

```
if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("start"))
```

or

```
if (line.toLowerCase().equals("start"))
```

Now, any case combination is alright, even `"START"`.

Last but not least: these `||` are not called pipes. If you use word "pipe" in programming context, a lot of people will think about [Unix pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), `|` symbol in the command line.

In Java `||` is "*logical* or operator", "*logical* or". To distinguish with "*binary* or", `|`, which is very different.

Comment: `str.toLowerCase().equals("something")` always looks like the dirty sister of `str.equalsIgnoreCase("something")` :D.

Answer (score 3):

Store the scanner input in a String like this:

```
 userInput = in.nextLine();
```

And then evaluate in your conditional statements